# The "cannot GET /URL" error with webpack production build although with webpack dev server it works fine

Tags: routes, react-router-v4, webpack-4, webpack-production

I am new to using react-router-4 and webpack-4.

I have a node server running locally configured with express. I get an "cannot GET /URL" when I run a webpack production build although the routes works fine with  Route links and within the page but once I do deep-linking or page refresh the page is not fetched.

Everything works fine with webpack-dev-server build.

I have the following webpack configuration for dev-server:-

```
devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../")
    },
```

but i am not sure configuration i need to make the webpack production build working. Is it the problem with webpack or express fetching the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your server.js file and ensure you're serving the index.html on every request. ensure the route is defined as "/*" and not "/"

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('build'));
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('server started at port 5000'));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'), (err) => {
if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
   });
});
```